# OwenIt \ Auditing \ Exceptions \ AuditingException Invalid UserResolver implementation using owen-it/laravel-auditing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using  owen-it/laravel-auditing for keeping history of changes of prices of products. But I am getting error while updating prices.

> OwenIt \ Auditing \ Exceptions \ AuditingException Invalid
>   UserResolver implementation

Prices do get updated but is history is not updated in database

**Products.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\Auditable;
use OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\UserResolver;

class Products extends Model implements Auditable, UserResolver
{
    use \OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;

    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $fillable = ['name','price','season','category','description','stock','image'];

    protected $auditInclude = [
        'name',
        'price',
    ];

    public static function resolveId()
    {
        return Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier() : null;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, @Faiez is using version [4.x](http://www.laravel-auditing.com/docs/4.1/general-configuration) or [5.x](http://www.laravel-auditing.com/docs/5.0/general-configuration) of the Auditing package, which registers the `User` resolver differently, when compared to the new [6.x](http://www.laravel-auditing.com/docs/6.0/general-configuration) version, which is what @btl was answering for.

You'll have to update your `audit.php` configuration file with the following, to make it work:

```
return [
    // ...
    'user' = [
        // ...
        'resolver' => App\Products::class,
        // ...
    ],
    // ...
];
```

However, I would advise you to move the `User` resolver to a different class (the `User` model, perhaps?), since it doesn't make much sense to have that in the `Products` model.

When in doubt, check the [documentation](http://www.laravel-auditing.com)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the resolver class in the `config/audit.php` file:

```
'resolver' => [
    'user'       => App\Products::class,
    'ip_address' => OwenIt\Auditing\Resolvers\IpAddressResolver::class,
    'user_agent' => OwenIt\Auditing\Resolvers\UserAgentResolver::class,
    'url'        => OwenIt\Auditing\Resolvers\UrlResolver::class,
],
```

Comment: You mean audit.php

Comment: Some classes are not being recognized. Even though still getting error

Comment: try adding a backslash before the ones not resolving like `\OwenIt\Auditing\Resolvers\IpAddressResolver::class,`

Comment: Nope not recognizing

Comment: `php artisan cache:clear` and `composer dumpautload` might fix it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164618/discussion-between-faiez-and-btl).